# Export telerik RadGrid to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, export-to-pdf

I have a Telerik RadGrid with NestedViewTemplate, when exporting it to PDF, it results in a corrupted file.

```
<NestedViewTemplate>
    <div runat="server" class="width-full">
        <span><%# Eval("Notes") %></span>
    </div>
</NestedViewTemplate>
```

Edit: the same grid but without this column (NestedViewTemplate) works fine and the export results in a well-formatted pdf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

There is an exception log says:

> Invalid XHTML. RadGrid has to render correct XHTML in order to export to PDF.  Parse error:  The 'br' start tag on line 778 position 6734 does not match the end tag of 'span'...

The note contains some HTML tags and the `<br>` tag is not valid XHTML tag, So, I replaced every `<br>` by `<br/>`, and it works properly now